# Laravel Error - Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

This is the code I am running:

```
  //FIXME
  $data = $request->all();
  $randomPassage = DB::table('passages')->inRandomOrder()->first();
  session()->put('passage', $randomPassage);
  echo($randomPassage);
```

This is the stack trace of errors:

```
in routes.php line 31
at HandleExceptions->handleError('4096', 'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\spring2017-cp-443965-441701\dev-develop\app\Http\routes.php', '31', array('request' => object(Request), 'data' => array('_token' => 'POr6dhVLdDza0O0jHLbWy9daKr3nkyA94EIm4wHM'), 'randomPassage' => object(stdClass))) in routes.php line 31
at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array(object(Request))) in compiled.php line 8519
at Route->runCallable(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8509
at Route->run(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8225
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3225
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13474
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 11964
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13213
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13150
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9948
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8226
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8217
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8207
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2419
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3286
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9948
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2366
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2350
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\spring2017-cp-443965-441701\dev-develop\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

I am just trying to print the value from the database. I know that I am trying to print an object, but I want to treat it as a string. The question is, how do I get the data as a string, such that I can echo it. Thanks for all the help!

Jack

UPDATE: When I can var_dump, I get:

```
object(stdClass)#176 (2) { ["passageName"]=> string(10) "Developers" ["content"]=> string(26) "Jack, Gen" }
```

Comment: `$randomPassage` is an array you can't put it in session. What you want to put in session?

Comment: I want to get a random passage from my database, then print that random passage.

Comment: can you plz tell me the db column name of table `passages` which want to store  in session?

Comment: The table name is passages. The column that I want is content, but there is another column with passageTitle.

Comment: Just store it as `json_encode()` and then `json_decode()` it in your view for an easy work around.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, can you be more specific on how I am supposed to use these commands? I am a bit confused - this is my first web project.

Comment: ^ See the update in the main question for more info. Thanks! ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to echo just one of the object parts:

```
echo $randomPassage->content;
```

Comment: But, how do I echo just one of the parts of the object?

Comment: if you want to echo just one of the parts don't use json_encode, try to do this:

echo $randomPassage->content;

Comment: That worked!!! Change you answer to "echo($randomPassage->content);", and I will mark it correct. Thanks!